# Adding values based on the order of elements in the list

Tags: c#

I am returning a list of products and i need to assign to each product a value form another list based on the product position in the list.I need to add the Additional text from productOrder to productInfo based on the row and return productInfo still as a list and keep it in the same order.

This is the model that containts the value

```
 public class ProductOrder
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalText { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the Product list where i need the value

```
internal class ProductInfo
    {
        public bool Support { get; set; }

        public string IconUrl { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalText { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how i assign data for testing purposes

```
  static List<ProductOrder> ReturnProductorder()
        {
            var productAdditionalInfo = new List<ProductOrder>()
            {
                new  ProductOrder()
                {
                    Row = 0,
                    AdditionalText = "TEST"
                },
                new  ProductOrder()
                {
                    Row = 3,
                    AdditionalText = "TEST"
                },
                 new  ProductOrder()
                {
                    Row = 10,
                    AdditionalText = "TEST"
                }
            };
            return productAdditionalInfo;
        }

        static List<ProductInfo> ReturnProductInfo()
        {
            var productAdditionalInfo = new List<ProductInfo>()
            {
                new ProductInfo()
                {
                  IconUrl = "test1",
                  Support = false,
                },
                 new ProductInfo()
                {
                  IconUrl = "test2",
                  Support = true,
                },
                  new ProductInfo()
                {
                  IconUrl = "test3",
                  Support = true,
                },
                 new ProductInfo()
                {
                  IconUrl = "test4",
                  Support = true,
                }

            };
            return productAdditionalInfo;
        }
```

And here is my logic

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var productOrder = ReturnProductorder();
            var productInfo = ReturnProductInfo();

           for(int i = 0; i < productOrder.Count; i++)
           {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productOrder[i].AdditionalText))
                {
                    var test2 = productInfo.ElementAt(productOrder[i].Row);
                    test2.AdditionalText = productOrder[i].AdditionalText;
                }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fixes the root of your issue, but it will fix the symptom. Check if `productInfo.Count` is greater than `Row`(the index):

```
for (int i = 0; i < productOrder.Count; i++)
{
    ProductOrder po = productOrder[i];
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(po.AdditionalText) && productInfo.Count > po.Row)
    {
        ProductInfo pi = productInfo.ElementAt(po.Row);
        pi.AdditionalText = po.AdditionalText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get the same results using linq:

```
   var resultList = productInfo.Select((productInfo, index) =>
        {
            var orderAdditionalText=productOrder.Where(w=>w.Row== index).Select(o=>o.AdditionalText).FirstOrDefault();

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderAdditionalText)
            {
                productInfo.AdditionalText =orderAdditionalText;
            }

            return productInfo;
        }).ToList();
```

I should mention that the resultList is a new list and has different reference than productinfo list.

Comment: Not same, you overwrite the `AdditionalText` with `null`, OP checks if it's `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, You're right. Edited my answer to implement that too. thanks